# Why does VIM's help page prepend every help command with ["x]?

Tags: vim, vi

When I look up the help page for a specific command, I see it formatted in a cryptic way. For example typing `:h x` brings up the following:

```
 ["x]<Del>  or                              <Del> x dl
 ["x]x      Delete [count] characters under and after the cursor
            [into register x] (not |linewise|).  Does the same as
            "dl"...
```

My question: What does the `["x]` before the command represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` and `]` indicate that this part is optional. The `"` means literally type `"` and `x` is an example of a register name. As it says in the description, if you use `x` here the deleted characters will be placed in register `x`. You could equally type `"ax` to delete the character and put it in the `a` register, or `"_x` to delete the character and send it to the black-hole register (discarding it completely).

Try `:help registers` to find out more about the available registers and how they are used.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.